# How to load a function during drupal update hook

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, updates

I created a update hook for my module, in which I would like to create some aliases with pathauto_create_alias.

I get the error `Call to undefined function pathauto_create_alias() in`.What is the best way to include this module so that the function does exist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pathauto_create_alias()` function is part of the `pathauto.inc` which is not automatically loaded.

To include this file in your `HOOK_update()`, can use:

`module_load_include('inc', 'pathauto');`